# How to change background color of the row after changing its value?

Tags: javascript, css, datatable, webix

How can I set a custom CSS (`background-color:red`, for example) style to the row which value had been changed?

I'm using Webix and the following function works well, but I'm not sure if there's a handy CSS implementation:

```
  on:{
    onAfterEditStop:function(state,editor){      
      if(state.old != state.value){
        webix.message("Row "+editor.row+" has been changed")
      }        
    }}
```

The full snippet is [here](http://webix.com/snippet/2a652696). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Example](http://webix.com/snippet/fc9bb720)

**Description:**
Simply added the function this.addRowCss to your event. Documentation can be found here: http://docs.webix.com/api__ui.datatable_addrowcss.html

if you want this to be temporary simply add a timer to the event then on timer expire do this.removeRowCss to remove this color.  If you need an example please ask.

---

**Code:**

```
var data = [
    { id:1, value:"Aa"},
    { id:2, value:"Bb"},
    { id:3, value:"Cc"},
    { id:4, value:"Dd"},
    { id:5, value:"Ee"},
    { id:6, value:"Ff"}
];


webix.ui({
  id:"table", view : "datatable", editable:true, 
  columns : [ 
    { id : "id", header : "", fillspace:0.1 }, 
    { id : "value", header : "Editable", editor : "text",  fillspace : 0.7 }
  ],
  data:data,  
  on:{
    onAfterEditStop:function(state,editor){      
      if(state.old != state.value){
        //this has to assign a css class name
        this.addRowCss(editor.row, "test");
        webix.message("Row "+editor.row+" has been changed")
      }        
    }}
  });
```

---

### [Example with timer for removing color](http://webix.com/snippet/cdc960f1)

```
var data = [
    { id:1, value:"Aa"},
    { id:2, value:"Bb"},
    { id:3, value:"Cc"},
    { id:4, value:"Dd"},
    { id:5, value:"Ee"},
    { id:6, value:"Ff"}
];

webix.ui({
  id:"table", view : "datatable", editable:true, 
  columns : [ 
    { id : "id", header : "", fillspace:0.1 }, 
    { id : "value", header : "Editable", editor : "text",  fillspace : 0.7 }
  ],
  data:data,  
  on:{
    onAfterEditStop:function(state, editor){
      if(state.old != state.value){
        var that = this;
        webix.message("Row "+editor.row+" has been changed")
        // 1500 is the number of milliseconds until color is changed back
        toggleRowCss(that, editor.row, "test", 1500);
      }        
    }
  }
});

function toggleRowCss(table, row, cssClass, timeout){
  //this has to assign a css class name
  table.addRowCss(row, cssClass);
  setTimeout(function(){ table.removeRowCss(row, cssClass); }, timeout);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! And could you please provide an example of the timer?Seems like I don't fully understand how to do such thing in Webix.

Comment: @letItReign timer example added